# How to integrate Stripe in Android using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, stripe-payments

User functionality required example -
User makes payment of $100 + first time fee. 6 months later another payment of $100 is automatically charged. With payments stopping after n number of total payments or until user manually stops.

Following this tutorial - https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android

Since I'm using firebase firestore for my backend I have created a token and charge by writing to the database, since I couldn't find any tutorial outlining a proper method that uses this combination. Is this how it should be done or is there a better way?

I have set up in my payment activity:

```
stripe = new Stripe(getApplicationContext(), "PUBLISHABLE_KEY_HIDDEN");

        confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cardToSave = mCardInputWidget.getCard();

                // Add details such as full name and address to card
                fillCardFields();

                if (!cardToSave.validateCard()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Card is invalid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                stripe.createToken(
                        cardToSave,
                        new TokenCallback() {
                            public void onSuccess(Token token) {
                                // Send token to your server
                                DocumentReference tokenRef;
                                tokenRef = db.collection("stripe_customers").document(mAuth.getUid()).collection("tokens").document();

                                tokenRef.set(token).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Token successfully added to database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                });

                                DocumentReference chargeRef;
                                chargeRef = db.collection("stripe_customers").document(mAuth.getUid()).collection("charges").document();
                                Map<String, Object> amount = new HashMap<>();

                                //Test amount of 5 - to be replaced with a variable
                                amount.put("amount", 5);
                                chargeRef.set(amount);
                                chargeRef.update("amount", 5).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        Log.e("chargeRef", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            public void onError(Exception error) {
                                // Show localized error message
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        error.getLocalizedMessage(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                ).show();
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
        });
```

Using this tutorial for firebase server functions using firestore -  https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/stripe

I copied the files from github into my project (is that how it's done?)

When I run my app and press the confirmButton a token is created firestore "stripe_customers/uid/tokens" an error field is generated and the error is "Missing required param: source." and cvc is null and cvc check is unchecked. What can I do to fix this/make payments and subscriptions work.

When I open https://firebase-id-hidden.firebaseapp.com/ it shows fields such as the following under "Credit Cards":

```
{{ source.brand }} …{{ source.last4 }} (exp. {{ source.exp_month }}/{{ source.exp_year }}) …
```

/public/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cloud Functions for Firebase (Stripe example)</title>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/3.5.2/firebaseui.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="app">
        <div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
        <div id="loader">&hellip;</div>
        <div v-if="currentUser">
            <h2>Hello {{ currentUser.email }},</h2>
            <button v-on:click="signOut">Sign out</button>
            <div v-if="stripeCustomerInitialized">
                <h3>Credit Cards</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li v-for="source in sources">
                <span v-if="source.id">
                  {{ source.brand }} &hellip;{{ source.last4 }}
                  (exp. {{ source.exp_month }}/{{ source.exp_year }})
                </span>
                        <span v-else>&hellip;</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div>
                    <h4>New</h4>
                    <div>
                        <label>
                            Number <input v-model="newCreditCard.number">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>
                            CCV <input v-model="newCreditCard.cvc">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>
                            Exp
                            <input v-model="newCreditCard.exp_month" size="2"> /
                            <input v-model="newCreditCard.exp_year" size="4">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>
                            Zip <input v-model="newCreditCard.address_zip">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button v-on:click="submitNewCreditCard">Add</button>
                        {{ newCreditCard.error }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h3>Charges</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li v-for="(charge, id) in charges">
                        {{ charge.amount }}
                        <span v-if="charge.error">
                  {{ charge.error }}
                </span>
                        <span v-else-if="charge.outcome">
                  {{ charge.outcome.seller_message }}
                  {{ charge.source.brand }} &hellip;{{ charge.source.last4 }}
                  (exp. {{ charge.source.exp_month }}/{{ charge.source.exp_year }})
                </span>
                        <span v-else>&hellip;</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <h4>New</h4>
                <div>
                    <label>
                        Card
                        <select v-model="newCharge.source">
                            <option :value="null">Default payment method</option>
                            <option v-for="(source, id) in sources" v-bind:value="source.id"
                                    v-if="source.id">
                                {{ source.brand }} &hellip;{{ source.last4 }}
                                (exp. {{ source.exp_month }}/{{ source.exp_year }})
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>
                        Amount <input v-model="newCharge.amount">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button v-on:click="submitNewCharge">Charge</button>
                    {{ newCharge.error }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div v-else>&hellip;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Import and configure the Firebase SDK -->
<!-- These scripts are made available when the app is served or deployed on Firebase Hosting -->
<!-- If you do not serve/host your project using Firebase Hosting see https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup -->
<script src="/__/firebase/5.9.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/5.9.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/5.9.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>

<!-- Import Firebase UI -->
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/3.5.2/firebaseui.js"></script>

<script>
      firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: "HIDDEN",
        authDomain: "HIDDEN",
        databaseURL: "HIDDEN",
        storageBucket: "HIDDEN",
        messagingSenderId: "HIDDEN"
      });
      Stripe.setPublishableKey('HIDDEN');
      var firebaseUI = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
      var firebaseAuthOptions = {
        callbacks: {
          signInSuccess: (currentUser, credential, redirectUrl) => { return false; },
          uiShown: () => { document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none'; }
        },
        signInFlow: 'popup',
        signInSuccessUrl: '/',
        signInOptions: [ firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID ],
        tosUrl: '/'
      };
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
        if (firebaseUser) {
          document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
          app.currentUser = firebaseUser;
          app.listen();
        } else {
          firebaseUI.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', firebaseAuthOptions);
          app.currentUser = null;
        }
      });
      var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          currentUser: null,
          sources: {},
          stripeCustomerInitialized: false,
          newCreditCard: {
            number: '4242424242424242',
            cvc: '111',
            exp_month: 1,
            exp_year: 2020,
            address_zip: '00000'
          },
          charges: {},
          newCharge: {
            source: null,
            amount: 2000
          }
        },
        ready: () => {
        },
        methods: {
          listen: function() {
            firebase.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(`${this.currentUser.uid}`).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
              this.stripeCustomerInitialized = (snapshot.data() !== null);
            }, () => {
              this.stripeCustomerInitialized = false;
            });
            firebase.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(`${this.currentUser.uid}`).collection('sources').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
             let newSources = {};
              snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                const id = doc.id;
                newSources[id] = doc.data();
              })
              this.sources = newSources;
            }, () => {
              this.sources = {};
            });
            firebase.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(`${this.currentUser.uid}`).collection('charges').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            let newCharges = {};
             snapshot.forEach(doc => {
               const id = doc.id;
               newCharges[id] = doc.data();
             })
             this.charges = newCharges;
            }, () => {
              this.charges = {};
            });
          },
          submitNewCreditCard: function() {
            Stripe.card.createToken({
              number: this.newCreditCard.number,
              cvc: this.newCreditCard.cvc,
              exp_month: this.newCreditCard.exp_month,
              exp_year: this.newCreditCard.exp_year,
              address_zip: this.newCreditCard.address_zip
            }, (status, response) => {
              if (response.error) {
                this.newCreditCard.error = response.error.message;
              } else {
                firebase.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(this.currentUser.uid).collection('tokens').add({token: response.id}).then(() => {
                  this.newCreditCard = {
                    number: '',
                    cvc: '',
                    exp_month: 1,
                    exp_year: 2017,
                    address_zip: ''
                  };
                });
              }
            });
          },
          submitNewCharge: function() {
            firebase.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(this.currentUser.uid).collection('charges').add({
              source: this.newCharge.source,
              amount: parseInt(this.newCharge.amount)
            });
          },
          signOut: function() {
            firebase.auth().signOut()
          }
        }
      });


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

/functions/index.js

```
/**
 * Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
//Causes error during deploy
//const logging = require('@google-cloud/logging')();
const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.token);
const currency = functions.config().stripe.currency || 'AUD';

// [START chargecustomer]
// Charge the Stripe customer whenever an amount is written to the Realtime database
exports.createStripeCharge = functions.firestore.document('stripe_customers/{userId}/charges/{id}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
      const val = snap.data();
      try {
        // Look up the Stripe customer id written in createStripeCustomer
        const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection(`stripe_customers`).doc(context.params.userId).get()
        const snapval = snapshot.data();
        const customer = snapval.customer_id
        // Create a charge using the pushId as the idempotency key
        // protecting against double charges
        const amount = val.amount;
        const idempotencyKey = context.params.id;
        const charge = {amount, currency, customer};
        if (val.source !== null) {
          charge.source = val.source;
        }
        const response = await stripe.charges.create(charge, {idempotency_key: idempotencyKey});
        // If the result is successful, write it back to the database
        return snap.ref.set(response, { merge: true });
      } catch(error) {
        // We want to capture errors and render them in a user-friendly way, while
        // still logging an exception with StackDriver
        console.log(error);
        await snap.ref.set({error: userFacingMessage(error)}, { merge: true });
        return reportError(error, {user: context.params.userId});
      }
    });
// [END chargecustomer]]

// When a user is created, register them with Stripe
exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
  const customer = await stripe.customers.create({email: user.email});
  return admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(user.uid).set({customer_id: customer.id});
});

// Add a payment source (card) for a user by writing a stripe payment source token to Realtime database
exports.addPaymentSource = functions.firestore.document('/stripe_customers/{userId}/tokens/{pushId}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
  const source = snap.data();
  const token = source.token;
  if (source === null){
    return null;
  }

  try {
    const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(context.params.userId).get();
    const customer =  snapshot.data().customer_id;
    const response = await stripe.customers.createSource(customer, {source: token});
    return admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(context.params.userId).collection("sources").doc(response.fingerprint).set(response, {merge: true});
  } catch (error) {
    await snap.ref.set({'error':userFacingMessage(error)},{merge:true});
    return reportError(error, {user: context.params.userId});
  }
});

// When a user deletes their account, clean up after them
exports.cleanupUser = functions.auth.user().onDelete(async (user) => {
  const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(user.uid).get();
  const customer = snapshot.data();
  await stripe.customers.del(customer.customer_id);
  return admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(user.uid).delete();
});

// To keep on top of errors, we should raise a verbose error report with Stackdriver rather
// than simply relying on console.error. This will calculate users affected + send you email
// alerts, if you've opted into receiving them.
// [START reporterror]
function reportError(err, context = {}) {
  // This is the name of the StackDriver log stream that will receive the log
  // entry. This name can be any valid log stream name, but must contain "err"
  // in order for the error to be picked up by StackDriver Error Reporting.
  const logName = 'errors';
  const log = logging.log(logName);

  // https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/ref_v2beta1/rest/v2beta1/MonitoredResource
  const metadata = {
    resource: {
      type: 'cloud_function',
      labels: {function_name: process.env.FUNCTION_NAME},
    },
  };

  // https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/ErrorEvent
  const errorEvent = {
    message: err.stack,
    serviceContext: {
      service: process.env.FUNCTION_NAME,
      resourceType: 'cloud_function',
    },
    context: context,
  };

  // Write the error log entry
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    log.write(log.entry(metadata, errorEvent), (error) => {
      if (error) {
       return reject(error);
      }
      return resolve();
    });
  });
}
// [END reporterror]

// Sanitize the error message for the user
function userFacingMessage(error) {
  return error.type ? error.message : 'An error occurred, developers have been alerted';
}
```

/functions/package.json

```
{
  "name": "stripe-functions",
  "description": "Stripe Firebase Functions",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/logging": "^4.5.1",
    "firebase-admin": "~7.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.2.1",
    "stripe": "^6.28.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint --max-warnings=0 .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Hi there, 
So what you are trying to achieve is recurring charges basically. What you are doing looks correct to me as long as your overall flow follows the following. 

1) using Stripe Android SDK to collect and tokenize credit card in your Android Application (this will create a token)
2) Pass token to your backend (firebase node server using Stripe-node) (sorry about my firebase terminology if I am wrong
3) Create a customer with the token and email (token will be saved and can be charged again)
4) Store the customer 
5) Charge the customer (the saved token(source) will be charged)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was caused by a outdated variable name in /functions/index.js

For the addPaymentSouce function in index.js, replace the line:
`const token = source.token;`
with
`const token = source.id;`